# Reporting on information held in Realms

Tags: realm, realm-mobile-platform

Am a little new to using Realm, but learning fast. I've seen that when using the Realm object server the default setting is that a new Realm is created for each new user. I also see that with quite some effort a Global realm can be created and permissions given to it, so that many users can access that realm. As I'm working on an app where users create orders, then the first approach seems more secure; each user would have access only to the orders created in that users Realm.

My question is, in this situation how would I be able to report on total order  information across users e.g. total order quantities/amounts for September for all orders taken? 
I haven't been able to find any reporting system or information about this. Any advice or hints & tips that would help me solve this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So after making many checks and hearing back from the guys at Realm, it seems that it is not currently possible to get summary info across Realms.
One solution suggested would be to create a "summary" realm and write total info to is as Im creating the other realms, which doesn't sound like a good solution.
So the only solution currently, that will allow you to get summary information across e.g. orders for different people, is to store the information in one Global Realm and set the permissions so that all users can access it.
A final note, Realm have told me that they plan to bring out an enhancement, that will help solve this issue, by letting you set securities for users within Global Realms. Hopefully that comes out soon :-)